# How can I parse a list to columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I've pulled some JSON data, but I have a list within a list I want to explode out. I have one list ORDERS and then a list within that called ITEMS.

I have converted to a data frame so that I have the information I need e.g.

```
Order Number    items
999999999       {'orderItemId': 1111111, 'sku': 'AAA-BBB'}
888888888       {'orderItemId': 2222222, 'sku': 'AAA-CCC'}
777777777       {'orderItemId': 3333333, 'sku': 'BBB-CCC'}
```

Both data types are now Objects - how can I parse/demlimit what is in the items column so I have this as as one dataframe e.g.

```
Order Number     orderItemId         sku
999999999       11111111            AAA-BBB
888888888       22222222            AAA-CCC
777777777       33333333            BBB-CCC
```

Right now, this is what I have to pull the data from the request, parse the ORDER data and then just select the orderNumber column from this order data and the items list

Any suggestions how this can be done cleaner appreciated

```
df = response.json()
df = (df["orders"])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
df = df[['orderNumber', 'items']]
df = df.explode('items')
```

Comment: My answer is below. But as a note. Make sure that the df you share is properly formatted.  'AAA-CCC  should be  'AAA-CCC'

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I've edited

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do to deal with the `items` column:

```
df['items'] = df["items"].apply(lambda x : dict(eval(x)))
df2 = df["items"].apply(pd.Series)
```

which return

```
   orderItemId      sku
0      1111111  AAA-BBB
1      2222222  AAA-CCC
2      3333333  BBB-CCC
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm not sure if there is something in my work that is preventing this working, I just get the error: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object

Comment: That is strange. How do you import the data? Is it a csv file?

Comment: Its a GET URL request - so is a model.Response that I've set as a dict and then converted to a data frame - I am just playing around with flatten_json to see if doing this when I import is a better approach